# Cronjob to push MongoDB Backup via git

Tags: debian, bash, cron, git

**Task:** Create a Cronjob that executes a bash script once every night. The bash script should do a mongoDB Backup and push it to a Git Repo.

So I created a **cronjob** as the root user via the `crontab -e` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/root
HOME=/root

0 2 * * * /path/script.sh > /path/script.log
```

This is the **script** that should be executed:

```
BAK="/path"

#MONGO="/usr/bin/mongo"
#MONGODUMP="/usr/bin/mongodump"
#GIT="/usr/bin/git"

echo "starting backup"
echo $BAK
/usr/bin/mongodump --username=myusername --password=mypassword --db=mydatabase --out=$BAK$
echo "backup created"
/usr/bin/git add .
/usr/bin/git commit -m "backup from `date +'%Y_%m_%d'`"
echo "committed"
/usr/bin/git push -u origin master
echo "pushed backup. done"
```

**Outcome**: Backups are being created but not pushed to the repo. Executing the script manually pushes the backups as desired. The Log only includes all the echos from the script.

Comment: make sure you're in the right directory when the cron job is executed. Maybe add a `cd` directive to be sure or change the `git add .` to `git add /your/full/path`

Comment: To me it feels like a bad idea to store database dumps in a git repository. Check [this programmers exchange Q&A](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/241109/is-backing-up-a-mysql-database-in-git-a-good-idea) for explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change directory to `"$BAK"` before issuing the git commands.

You explicitly write your backups to `$BAK$` but when you run the `gid add .` you will be in the home directory of the user that is running the cron job. In this case that will be `/root`.

---

Here is a test script

```
pwd >/tmp/atest.out
touch ./atest.file
```

When run from root's crontab with

```
* * * * * /home/iain/atest
```

The contents of /tmp/atest.out

> /root

So where is ./atest.file

```
ls -l /home/iain/atest.file
ls: cannot access /home/iain/atest.file: No such file or directory
```

Hmm

```
ls -l /root/atest.file
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Nov 16 13:24 /root/atest.file
```

Bingo!. It does not matter that you are running the script from git's home directory. The working directory is in this case is /root.

```
/usr/bin/git add .
```

is adding the current working directory, which unless you have changed it is `/root`.

Comment: the script is in the gits root directory. so that does not solve it

Comment: How's about you actually make the change I suggest, then come back and thank me for solving your problem.

Comment: I already tried it out and it does not work. Thank you though for the attempt though

Comment: Then there is something you are not telling us. It really is the solution to the problem described.